# How to invoke a controller using a button in Spring-mvc?

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC.
I have a home page called `index.jsp`

```
<a href="register.htm"> Register an Employee</a>
<input type="button" onclick="register.htm" value="REGISTER">
```

When i click on a link `Register an Employee` , the flow comes into the `handleRequest` but when i click on submit button nothing happened.

My handleRequest method look like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("register");
        return mav;     
    }
```

How i can do this?

Comment: please post your applicationcontext.xml and the rest of your controller class.

Comment: Is it needed ? All beans are loading properly.

Comment: nope, it's just your button that has an issue, sorry i didn't read the question properly, your button does not trigger a page reload as onClick expects javascript, either change it to a regular submit button, or redirect using javascript like Pratap Murukutla suggests

Comment: is your form being submitted after onclick?

Comment: if it is working for link i think there are no issues in controllers..Please check your jsp page..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this..

```
<input type="button"  onclick="location.href='/register.htm'" value="Register" >
```

Comment: Thanks . Can you explain a little bit ? Why we need to add location.href?

Comment: onClick expects JavaScript code... pasting a URL in as a line of JS results in syntax error, thus you need the location.href=...

Comment: @Thinker Hey Please make the correct answer tick so that others can benifit.

Answer (score 1):

location.href should be avoided as it uses RequestMethod.GET instead of RequestMethod.POST. This is security vulnerability if you use GET method to submit forms.
Use the following example:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/

Comment: Please put code in answer so if the linked resource goes down you can still see the information online